# why does ID3 Decision tree algorithm not give the best decision tree?

Tags: machine-learning, decision-trees, supervised-learning

I was going through ID3 algorithm, and what I believe is it incorporates Greedy Search rule to get come up with the decision tree. If it gives the best split possible at every stage, how does it not give the best decision tree possible?

Comment: It's a local optimum, not a global one. All tree building algorithms are merely heuristics.

Comment: If you want the best decision tree, you need the "optimal decision tree", which you can get nowadays. Just have a look into the vast literature.

Comment: Greedy algorithms only rarely guarantee a globally optimal solution.

Comment: Can you name a better algorithm than ID3 for a single tree?